# VALIGN in reportlab TableStyle apparently without effect

Tags: python, formatting, reportlab

So, for a while now I have been struggling with this one. I know there are a lot of similar questions with good answers, and I have tried these answers, but the code I have basically reflects the answers given.

I am writing code to automatically generate matching exercises for worksheets. All this information should be in a table. And the text should all be aligned to the top of the cells.

Here is what I have now:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Table,         TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import cm

document = []
doc = SimpleDocTemplate('example.pdf', pagesize=A4, rightMargin=72, leftMargin=72, topMargin=72)
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

definitions = []
i, a = 1, 65
table = []
for x in range(1, 10):
    line = []
    line.append(Paragraph(str(i), styles['BodyText']))
    line.append(Paragraph('Vocabulary', styles['BodyText']))
    line.append(Paragraph(chr(a), styles['BodyText']))
    line.append(Paragraph('Often a multi-line definition of the vocabulary. But then, sometimes something short and sweet.', styles['BodyText']))
    table.append(line)
    i += 1
    a += 1

t = Table(table, colWidths=(1*cm, 4*cm, 1*cm, None))
t.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('VALIGN', (1, 1), (-1, -1), 'TOP')
]))

document.append(t)
doc.build(document)
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Love the story in you profile, I wished my teachers back in high school would have the same attitude!

Comment: Thanks! I had to go back and read it again, but it's still true. I'm not going to lie: today it's given me a few gray hairs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the way you are indexing the `TableStyle`. The indexing in Reportlab starts at `(0, 0)` for first row, first column. So in your case `(1, 1)` only applies the styling to everything below the first row and right of the first column.

The correct way would be to use:

```
('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP')
```

This will apply the styling to all cells in the `Table`.

Comment: Thanks for the patient answer. That worked great. I don't know why I couldn't see it myself, but I'm glad you did.

Comment: Is there a way to align text to the top_center?.. I have tried using ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP_CENTER') but it basically aligns text to the center of the cell rather than the top center.